# Determining image of $e^{iz^2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the complex mapping $$ z \mapsto w(z) = e^{iz^2}. $$ I need to describe the image of $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. for what $w$ is there a $z$ such that $w(z)  = w$? Also, for what $w$ is such a $z$ unique, and if not unique, how many are there?

I wrote this mapping as $$ \rho e^{i \phi^2} = w(z) = e^{iz^2} = e^{i(x + iy)^2} = e^{i (x^2 - y^2)} e^{-2xy} = e^{-2xy} ( \cos(x^2 - y^2) + i \sin(x^2 - y^2) )$$ and so $\rho = e^{-2xy}$ and $\phi^2 = x^2 - y^2$. But I'm not sure how to determine the image from this information. Some help would be appreciated.

Comment: Best to think of it as a chain of compositions: you're taking $z$, squaring it, multiplying that by $i$, and then taking $e^{that}$. Looking at the image at each step of this chain makes it simpler to keep track of things.

Comment: @πr8: +1 for $e^{that}$. :-)

Comment: Picard's theorem says that the range of a holomorphic entire function can miss at most one complex number. Do you know a complex number which can't be of the form $e^z$?

Comment: So the image is the whole $w$ plane except zero?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $f(z) = e^z$, then $f(\mathbb C) = \mathbb C \setminus \{0\}.$ We are looking at $f(iz^2)$ and $iz^2$ maps $\mathbb C$ onto ...